# Envoy - multiple path match and path rewrite

Tags: envoyproxy

I don't know why but I am getting 503 on upstream host. I can get to connect to envoy but from envoy is communication stopped by 503 status.

I would like to match the local path, rewrite it to remote path and call the upstream
Is my envoy bootstrap configuration correct?

Here is the code:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: envoy_listener
    address:
      socket_address:
        protocol: TCP
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 9000
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          common_http_protocol_options:
            idle_timeout: 600s
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
              log_format:
                json_format:
                  "timestamp": "%START_TIME%"
                  "protocol": "%PROTOCOL%"
                  "duration": "%DURATION%"
                  "response_code": "%RESPONSE_CODE%"
                  "user_agent": "%REQ(USER-AGENT)%"
          route_config:
            name: routes
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: 1po
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  path_match_policy:
                    name: envoy.path.match.uri_template.uri_template_matcher
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.path.match.uri_template.v3.UriTemplateMatchConfig
                      path_template: "/test"
                route:
                  path_rewrite_policy:
                    name: envoy.path.rewrite.uri_template.uri_template_rewriter
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.path.rewrite.uri_template.v3.UriTemplateRewriteConfig
                      path_template_rewrite: "/imghp"
                  cluster: "recommendations"
                  retry_policy:
                    retry_on: "5xx"
                    num_retries: 0
              - match:
                  path_match_policy:
                    name: envoy.path.match.uri_template.uri_template_matcher
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.path.match.uri_template.v3.UriTemplateMatchConfig
                      path_template: "/test2"
                route:
                  path_rewrite_policy:
                    name: envoy.path.rewrite.uri_template.uri_template_rewriter
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.path.rewrite.uri_template.v3.UriTemplateRewriteConfig
                      path_template_rewrite: "/translate"
                  cluster: "access"
                  retry_policy:
                    retry_on: "5xx"
                    num_retries: 0
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
  - name: recommendations
    typed_extension_protocol_options:
      envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions
        upstream_http_protocol_options:
          auto_sni: true
        common_http_protocol_options:
          idle_timeout: 600s
        explicit_http_config:
          http2_protocol_options:
            max_concurrent_streams: 100
    connect_timeout: 5.0s
    circuit_breakers:
      thresholds:
        - priority: DEFAULT
          max_connections: 1024
        - priority: DEFAULT
          max_pending_requests: 1024
        - priority: DEFAULT
          max_requests: 1024
        - priority: DEFAULT
          max_retries: 0
    type: STRICT_DNS
    dns_refresh_rate: 3600s
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: recommendations
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: google.com
                port_value: 443
  - name: access
    typed_extension_protocol_options:
      envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions
        upstream_http_protocol_options:
          auto_sni: true
        common_http_protocol_options:
          idle_timeout: 600s
        explicit_http_config:
          http2_protocol_options:
            max_concurrent_streams: 100
    connect_timeout: 5.0s
    circuit_breakers:
      thresholds:
        - priority: DEFAULT
          max_connections: 1024
        - priority: DEFAULT
          max_pending_requests: 1024
        - priority: DEFAULT
          max_requests: 1024
        - priority: DEFAULT
          max_retries: 0
    type: STRICT_DNS
    dns_refresh_rate: 3600s
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: access
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: yahoo.com
                port_value: 443
admin:
  access_log:
  - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
    typed_config:
      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
  address:
    socket_address:
      protocol: TCP
      address: 127.0.0.1
      port_value: 9045
```

I am getting with curl this below:

```
{
   "upstream_cluster":"recommendations",
   "downstream_transport_failure_reason":null,
   "response_code":503,
   "downstream_remote_address":"127.0.0.1:41770",
   "request_duration":0,
   "response_tx_duration":null,
   "duration":0,
   "timestamp":"2023-06-09T18:14:52.599Z",
   "connection_termination_details":null,
   "upstream_request_attempt_count":1,
   "upstream_local_address":null,
   "grpc_status":"Unavailable",
   "virtual_cluster_name":null,
   "upstream_transport_failure_reason":"immediate_connect_error:_Network_is_unreachable",
   "protocol":"HTTP/1.1",
   "response_duration":null,
   "request_tx_duration":null,
   "connection_id":0,
   "upstream_remote_address":"[2a00:1450:4014:80a::200e]:443",
   "upstream_host":"[2a00:1450:4014:80a::200e]:443",
   "upstream_protocol":null,
   "path":"/test",
   "downstream_handshake_duration":null,
   "response_flags":"UF,URX",
   "stream_id":"48bd2614-3e54-4c77-8adc-d37a1b148130",
   "route_name":null,
   "user_agent":"curl/7.74.0",
   "response_code_details":"upstream_reset_before_response_started{connection_failure,immediate_connect_error:_Network_is_unreachable}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few parameters in your configuration, and some you have set are creating issues. Here's a Git patch you can apply to your config file in your question (and some explanations after):

```
diff --git a/envoy.yaml b/envoy.yaml
--- a/envoy.yaml
+++ b/envoy.yaml
@@ -44,6 +44,7 @@ static_resources:
                     typed_config:
                       "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.path.rewrite.uri_template.v3.UriTemplateRewriteConfig
                       path_template_rewrite: "/imghp"
+                  auto_host_rewrite: true
                   cluster: "recommendations"
                   retry_policy:
                     retry_on: "5xx"
@@ -60,6 +61,7 @@ static_resources:
                     typed_config:
                       "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.path.rewrite.uri_template.v3.UriTemplateRewriteConfig
                       path_template_rewrite: "/translate"
+                  auto_host_rewrite: true
                   cluster: "access"
                   retry_policy:
                     retry_on: "5xx"
@@ -93,6 +95,7 @@ static_resources:
           max_retries: 0
     type: STRICT_DNS
     dns_refresh_rate: 3600s
+    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
     load_assignment:
       cluster_name: recommendations
       endpoints:
@@ -102,17 +105,11 @@ static_resources:
               socket_address:
                 address: google.com
                 port_value: 443
+    transport_socket:
+      name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
+      typed_config:
+        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
   - name: access
-    typed_extension_protocol_options:
-      envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions:
-        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions
-        upstream_http_protocol_options:
-          auto_sni: true
-        common_http_protocol_options:
-          idle_timeout: 600s
-        explicit_http_config:
-          http2_protocol_options:
-            max_concurrent_streams: 100
     connect_timeout: 5.0s
     circuit_breakers:
       thresholds:
@@ -126,6 +123,7 @@ static_resources:
           max_retries: 0
     type: STRICT_DNS
     dns_refresh_rate: 3600s
+    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
     load_assignment:
       cluster_name: access
       endpoints:
@@ -135,6 +133,10 @@ static_resources:
               socket_address:
                 address: yahoo.com
                 port_value: 443
+    transport_socket:
+      name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
+      typed_config:
+        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
 admin:
   access_log:
   - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
```

### Explanations

I have used envoy 1.26.2, and the config (once patched) works.

- in order to change the host header from `localhost` to `google.com` or `yahoo.com` when forwarding the request to the cluster, you need to set `auto_host_rewrite: true`
- not sure if it's required in your case, but `dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY` was required in mine as I was running envoy using Docker: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/20542#issuecomment-1081448431
- you need to add a TLS transport configuration for both clusters (`transport_socket` with `envoy.transport_sockets.tls`) because both `google.com` and `yahoo.com` are reached using HTTPS
- `yahoo.com` is not using HTTP/2, so `envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions` must be removed